# SQL unable to insert data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I've been trying to insert data in a database table, however I keep getting an the error "ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification"

The table I trying to input data into;

```
CREATE
TABLE LOT
(
Lot_ID         INTEGER NOT NULL ,
Reserve_Prices NUMBER NOT NULL ,
Asking_prices NUMBER NOT NULL ,
Selling_prices NUMBER NOT NULL ,
Authorship     VARCHAR2 (200) NOT NULL ,
Origin         VARCHAR2 (200) ,
Age           INTEGER ,
"Size" VARCHAR2 (200) ,   
Condition VARCHAR2 (200) ,
Authenticity VARCHAR2 (200) ,
Description              VARCHAR2 (200) ,
Sold                     VARCHAR2 (3) NOT NULL ,
INVOICE_Invoice_ID       INTEGER NOT NULL ,
EVENT_Location_ID        INTEGER NOT NULL ,
SELLER_Seller_ID         INTEGER NOT NULL ,
AUCTIONEER_Auctioneer_ID INTEGER NOT NULL ,
BIDDER_Bidder_ID         INTEGER NOT NULL
 ) ;
 ALTER TABLE LOT ADD CONSTRAINT LOT_PK PRIMARY KEY ( Lot_ID ) ;
```

the insert statements;

```
Insert into lot (lot_ID,Reserve_Prices,Asking_prices,Selling_prices,Authorship,Origin,Age,"Size",Condition,Authenticity,Description,Sold,INVOICE_Invoice_ID,EVENT_Location_ID,SELLER_Seller_ID,AUCTIONEER_Auctioneer_ID,BIDDER_Bidder_ID,) values (001,1000,1000,1000,'unknown','unknown',200,'small','good','authentic','a small ceramic teacup','yes',001,001,001,001,001);
Insert into lot (lot_ID,Reserve_Prices,Asking_prices,Selling_prices,Authorship,Origin,Age,"Size",Condition,Authenticity,Description,Sold,INVOICE_Invoice_ID,EVENT_Location_ID,SELLER_Seller_ID,AUCTIONEER_Auctioneer_ID,BIDDER_Bidder_ID,) values (002,2500,2500,2500,'unknown','US',15,'large','good','unknown','senator ring','no',002,002,002,002,002);
Insert into lot (lot_ID,Reserve_Prices,Asking_prices,Selling_prices,Authorship,Origin,Age,"Size",Condition,Authenticity,Description,Sold,INVOICE_Invoice_ID,EVENT_Location_ID,SELLER_Seller_ID,AUCTIONEER_Auctioneer_ID,BIDDER_Bidder_ID,) values (003,100,100,100,'ships and Co.','London',200,'medium','poor','authentic','Ships and Co. medicine box','yes',003,003,003,003,003);
```

this code works for every other table but when running this one I only get an error

Comment: i think `lot_ID` needs to be `Lot_ID`

Comment: Can you shared the message error that you get?
the last column on insert command has a comma "," at the end e there's no other column after that "AUCTIONEER_Auctioneer_ID,BIDDER_Bidder_ID,) "

Comment: correct (remove) the comma at the end of your filed names on inserts and it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your individual insert statements, you have an extra comma after BIDDER_Bidder_ID in your field declarations, so it's looking for another field that isn't being specified. Try removing those commas.

Comment: Thank you very much, this coupled with the NUMBER data type comment has helped alot.

Comment: Sure thing.  The little syntax squiggly was tough to see ;).

Answer (score 0):

Check this BIDDER_Bidder_ID,
You've insert a comma in the end of insert query.. fix this removing the last comma